# What do the device numbers mean in the storage device path? (i.e. 0:0:0:1)

Tags: linux

If I run the following:

```
$ ls -ld /sys/block/sd*/device
```

I see this...

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 23 20:25 /sys/block/sda/device -> ../../../1:0:0:0
```

What do the numbers `1:0:0:0` represent? I see on different systems the output can be `0:0:0:0` for sda and `0:0:0:1` for sdb. Do each of these digits have some significance? Or better yet, where can I find the documentation on this path format?

Answer (score 1):

This is SCSI nomenclature: the four numbers represent the host (controller), bus, target (device) and LUN (logical unit number). Linux treats most disk devices in the same way, even if they’re not SCSI devices. SATA devices are generally the only device on their “controller” (which maps to a SATA port), so they usually appear as *N*:0:0:0.

See [the `lsscsi` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/lsscsi) for a description of this format. (This isn’t canonical, but it’s the best I’ve found.)